# How to get correct fileName function line when calling CocoaLumberjack from delegating function

Tags: ios, cocoalumberjack

I am using DDLogFormatter to format message and add there fileName, function and line to my logging but I don't call CocoaLumberjack directly , instead delegating so I can do some syntactic improvements. But now when I implemented it I realized I am getting wrong information in formatter, not actually wrong it's correct but I want to know one step before in stack to put it in log statement so I get fileName, function and line where actually calling happened to my delegating method.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround as #function, #file, #line for swift... for obj-c calls I will omit this info for now.